# google chrome extensions: Show ssr or csr

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, server-side-rendering

hello I am looking for a tool where I can see how the website rendering is done. Whether the website Server Side Rendering or Client Side Rendering

Comment: Please check [Headless Chrome: an answer to server-side rendering JS sites](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/puppeteer/articles/ssr) documentation. The techniques in the documentation show how to use **Puppeteer's APIs** to add server-side rendering (SSR) capabilities to an Express web server.

Answer (score 3):

Open Chrome devtools, and then click the tab of 'Network' - 'Doc',find your document request,and right click, select the 'Open in Sources panel'.You can check the HTML markup of original response to find out whether ssr or csr.